# Ajax table doesn't show anything

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm creating a table using ajax and php but there's one problem, the table isn't showing in my div. I'm really new to ajax so I don't really fully understand it yet.

Here's my div:

```
<div class="body" id="live-data">
</div>
```

Here's the ajax code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    function fetch_data() {  
        $.ajax({  
            url:"fetch.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            success:function(data){  
                $('#live_data').html(data);  
            }  
        });  
    }
    fetch_data(); 
});
```

And here's fetch.php:

```
<?php

include('../global/db.php');

$output = ''; 
$sql ="SELECT * FROM students WHERE status = '0' AND stud_grade = '$level_id' ORDER BY date_enrolled DESC";  
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);  
$output .= '  
<div class="table-responsive">  
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover dataTable js-exportable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="135" class="noExport">Action</th>
                <th width="90">LRN</th>
                <th width="20">Level</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th width="20">Gender</th>
                <th width="60">Type</th>
                <th width="105" style="font-size: 14px!important;">Date Enrolled</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        $output .= ' 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn bg-cyan btn-xs waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $stud_id ?>">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                        <span>Profile</span>
                    </button>&nbsp;
                    <button type="button" class="btn bg-orange btn-xs waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $stud_id ?><?php echo $stud_id ?>">
                        <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                        <span>Parent</span>
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_lrn ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_grade ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_lname ?>, <?php echo $stud_fname ?> <?php echo $stud_mname ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_gender ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_type ?></td>
                <td style="font-size: 12px!important;"><?php echo $date_enrolled = date("M-d-Y g:i A", strtotime($date_enrolled));?></td>
            </tr>
        ';
    }
}

else {  
        $output .= '
            <tr>  
                <td colspan="12">Data not Found</td>  
            </tr>';  
}  

 $output .= '
        </tbody>
    </table>  
</div>';  

echo $output;  

?>
```

It would great if anyone could help because I just don't know why it doesn't work

Edit: 
I've changed the code so it returns the data in the console tab and here's what shows up:

```
<div class="table-responsive">  
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover dataTable js-exportable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="135" class="noExport">Action</th>
                <th width="90">LRN</th>
                <th width="20">Level</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th width="20">Gender</th>
                <th width="60">Type</th>
                <th width="105" style="font-size: 14px!important;">Date Enrolled</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn bg-cyan btn-xs waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $stud_id ?>">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                        <span>Profile</span>
                    </button>&nbsp;
                    <button type="button" class="btn bg-orange btn-xs waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $stud_id ?><?php echo $stud_id ?>">
                        <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                        <span>Parent</span>
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_lrn ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_grade ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_lname ?>, <?php echo $stud_fname ?> <?php echo $stud_mname ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_gender ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_type ?></td>
                <td style="font-size: 12px!important;"><?php echo $date_enrolled = date("M-d-Y g:i A", strtotime($date_enrolled));?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn bg-cyan btn-xs waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $stud_id ?>">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                        <span>Profile</span>
                    </button>&nbsp;
                    <button type="button" class="btn bg-orange btn-xs waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $stud_id ?><?php echo $stud_id ?>">
                        <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                        <span>Parent</span>
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_lrn ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_grade ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_lname ?>, <?php echo $stud_fname ?> <?php echo $stud_mname ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_gender ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_type ?></td>
                <td style="font-size: 12px!important;"><?php echo $date_enrolled = date("M-d-Y g:i A", strtotime($date_enrolled));?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn bg-cyan btn-xs waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $stud_id ?>">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                        <span>Profile</span>
                    </button>&nbsp;
                    <button type="button" class="btn bg-orange btn-xs waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $stud_id ?><?php echo $stud_id ?>">
                        <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                        <span>Parent</span>
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_lrn ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_grade ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_lname ?>, <?php echo $stud_fname ?> <?php echo $stud_mname ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_gender ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_type ?></td>
                <td style="font-size: 12px!important;"><?php echo $date_enrolled = date("M-d-Y g:i A", strtotime($date_enrolled));?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn bg-cyan btn-xs waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $stud_id ?>">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                        <span>Profile</span>
                    </button>&nbsp;
                    <button type="button" class="btn bg-orange btn-xs waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $stud_id ?><?php echo $stud_id ?>">
                        <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                        <span>Parent</span>
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_lrn ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_grade ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_lname ?>, <?php echo $stud_fname ?> <?php echo $stud_mname ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_gender ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $stud_type ?></td>
                <td style="font-size: 12px!important;"><?php echo $date_enrolled = date("M-d-Y g:i A", strtotime($date_enrolled));?></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>  
</div>
```

So it clearly returns the correct data but it just doesn't show up in the live-data div

Comment: Have you looked at what is coming back in `data` in the debugger?

Comment: I would also place the function outside of `$(document).ready( function() {}`, only call it from within, when document is fully loaded, console.log(data) in your success callback and see that it's running.

Comment: Build up from something simpler - change your fetch.php to return a simple `<div>test</div>`.

Comment: it doesn't return even a simple div :(

Comment: it returns the table in the debugger, but it doesn't show up in the div

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Be warned that the given SQL query is open for SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take a look in your html where is your div. Your div id says "live-data" and in the ajax code you mentioned to fetch data for div id "#live_data" instead of "#live-data".
Maybe changing them for same name can solve your problem. I would use for thr div id and in the ajax same id names like "#liveData".

Example (same code, just edited to the right IDs, compare with your original):

Your HTML div

```
<div class="body" id="liveData">
</div>
```

Your ajax code

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    function fetch_data() {  
        $.ajax({  
            url:"fetch.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            success:function(data){  
                $('#liveData').html(data);  
            }  
        });  
    }
    fetch_data(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append the correct Id of the div tag in sucess function